# Pandas: group multiple columns under one header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

**Set-up**

I have a pandas dataframe `df` consisting out of multiple columns, with headers like,

```
| id | x, single room | x, double room | y, single room | y, double room |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ⋮          ⋮               ⋮                 ⋮                 ⋮
```

---

**Problem**

I'd like to group the columns starting with `x` and starting with `y` under headers in the following way,

```
     |             x             |             y             |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | single room | double room | single room | double room |
--------------------------------------------------------------
   ⋮        ⋮             ⋮              ⋮             ⋮
```

How do I go about?

Comment: This can be done (more or less) with [MultiIndexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), but main problem is get `id` to last level:

```
col =['id','x, single room','x, double room','y, single room','y, double room' ]
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1]], columns=col)
print (df)
   id  x, single room  x, double room  y, single room  y, double room
0   1               1               1               1               1
```

---

```
#create tuples from MultiIndex
a = df.columns.str.split(', ', expand=True).values
print (a)
[('id', nan) ('x', 'single room') ('x', 'double room') ('y', 'single room')
 ('y', 'double room')]

#swap values in NaN and replace NAN to ''
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('', x[0]) if pd.isnull(x[1]) else x for x in a])
print (df)
               x                       y            
  id single room double room single room double room
0  1           1           1           1           1
```

Old solution:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.str.rsplit(', ', expand=True).values.tolist())
mask = a[1].isnull()
a.loc[mask, [0,1]] = a.loc[mask, [1,0]].values
a[0] = a[0].fillna('')
df.columns = a.set_index([0,1]).index
df.columns.names = ('', '')
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: I have nicer solution, give me a sec.

Comment: @jezrael It's really fantastic.